# 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, proxy, apache

I am trying to access the featureInfo in my application and I keep getting 502 Bad Gateway Network error. In teh console log under the response tab I am getting this error,

```
This proxy does not allow you to access that location (castle.iplantcollaborative.org:8080).
```

The GET param is,

```
http://castle.iplantcollaborative.org:8080/geoserver/wms/?LAYERS=opengeo%3APimaPine,opengeo%3ABIEN_Species_Richness_Margalef,opengeo%3ABIEN_Species_Richness,opengeo%3ABIEN_Species_Richness_Margalef_Interpolated&QUERY_LAYERS=opengeo%3APimaPine,opengeo%3ABIEN_Species_Richness_Margalef,opengeo%3ABIEN_Species_Richness,opengeo%3ABIEN_Species_Richness_Margalef_Interpolated&STYLES=,,,&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=-18295967.087793%2C-10684061.894102%2C18295967.087793%2C10684062.234102&FEATURE_COUNT=10&HEIGHT=546&WIDTH=935&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fvnd.ogc.gml&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&X=174&Y=140
```

My `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi` has the domain's url added to it's allowed hosts. The apache error.log file was giving this error,

```
Permission denied: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi' failed
```

But when I changed the `chmod` for the proxy.cgi file to `root:root` it is not giving that error but it continues to give 502 Bad Gateway. I know I need to make some changes somewhere in the user permissions but not sure where?

Any idea what I should correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to simply clear the browser history. This is so dumb :P

Just make sure the ip address or the domain name is added to the allowed hosts in the `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi` script.

Comment: this was the answer to my questions! thanks a lot! i use Openlayers and with setting the OpenLayers.ProxyHost in my code, it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

> solved the problem using proxy.php.

I got the file from the last Mapbuilder app, and its just copy the
proxy.php file in my /var/www/ directory.
In openlayers edit/add the line

OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/proxy.php?url="

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2011-March/019840.html

response to comment:
To setup the proxy see Geoserver Documentation.
http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html

Comment: can u share where the proxy.php is?

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: thanks I did not know about the direct proxy to Geoserver. Thanks for sharing

Comment: the above link is broken.

Comment: @Zach fixed link

Comment: I'm having the same problem but in XAMP but using OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url="  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111982/proxy-cgi-for-openlayers-reading-from-georss-but-not-from-wfs